# Why does my phone split long text messages into multiple messages?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a galaxy s6 on verizon.

My friend has an iPhone 5 on sprint.

When I send him long text messages, they appear as one message on my screen. On his screen they're broken up into multiple messages.

I Googled it and it said that's just a problem with cross carrier messaging.

He said no because his other friend has verizon and sends him long texts on on a s6 edge and that doesn't happen.

Why does my phone split texts into multiple messages instead of keeping it one long message?

I use the default sms app and I tried using Googles messenger app and it still happens.